# Parsing HTML fragments with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, parsing, fragment

I receive the following HTML fragment via a Server-Sent Event resource:

```
<div id="ix_463" class="bubble bubble-l">Twice<div class="time-l">11:43 AM</div></div>
```

How can I convert that to a div with Jquery to get the ***id*** of the div?

My Attempt:

```
var x=$.parseHTML('<div id="ix_463" class="bubble bubble-l">Twice<div class="time-l">11:43 AM</div></div>');
```

does not work.

Comment: You don't need to parse it, just put the string in to a jQuery wrapper, then get the `id` via `.prop()`: http://jsfiddle.net/e5qeaq6h/